# Xwiki Create virtual wiki - problem adding a class

Tags: xwiki

I'm trying to create a virtual wiki but I already struggle with

> In your Class Editor, create a new class called "XWikiServerClass"

Further reading in the DevGuide / DataModel shows that I'm not alone. I understand the words saying but I don't get the how-to as there is no option in the class-editior of creating new classes. Navigating to class editor shows an info box

> No class is defined in this wiki document. You can create one by adding properties from the panel on your right, or you can choose another class to edit from the list below.

Ok, I added 'XWikiServerClass' and would have expected to be able to add a type class but that's not possible. I've tried a few properties but nothing shows up as a class in class editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you give more info on how you set up your wiki ?

As far as I know, you should have installed xwiki-enterprise-manager-web-x.y.war and modify your setup to fit your needs.

Second, you should have imported "xwiki-enterprise-manager-wiki-administrator-x.y.xar into your empty instance.

This xar archive already contains the XWikiServerClass and a very handy set of pages to automate the creation of virtual wikis.

Comment: I think what hold me back was lack of support for postgres for the automated solution with the administrator-xar. But I'll check that again asap - thanks. For now I have postponed the virtual installation and keep with several instances of the 'standard' wiki.

Comment: Mmmm, I don't have time to recheck now, but I think the lack of support of anything but mysql is due to the fact that the virtual wiki database is created on the fly using a sql script that is hard-encoded in the xwiki code. Hence it is not really an administrator xar problem. I think a jira issue could be added and a patch provided to the team, they are very responsive for this kind of improvement.